# Rings and unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The set $R = {([0]; [2]; [4]; [6]; [8])}$ is a subring of $Z_{10}$. (You do not need to
prove this.) Prove that it has a unity and explain why this is surprising.
Also, prove that it is a field and explain why that is also surprising.

This sis a HW Question.
The unity is not [0] is it ?? Could I get a hint ???

Comment: Why not just try multiplying elements of this ring by other elements and seeing if one of them behaves as a multiplicative identity?  It won't take very long.

Comment: What is an "eld"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $[6]\times[a]=[a]$ for $a=0,2,4,6,$ and $8$.  See if you can do the rest!

Comment: Got it thanks again Jared. I am just studying for a midterm tomorrow which is why I am asking tonnes of questions.